# Infinite sum of products of four Bessel functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, bessel-functions

The discrete Schrödinger equation for two interacting electrons in 1D under an electric field reads
$$
E\psi_{mn}=[(m+n)F+U\delta_{mn}]\psi_{mn}-\psi_{m+1,n}-\psi_{m-1,n}
-\psi_{m,n+1}-\psi_{m,n-1}\ .
$$
Since Bessel functions solve the one-electron problem [see,e.g., Eur. J. Phys. **31** (2010) 639], I looked for a solution to the two-electron problem of the form
$$
\psi_{mn}=\sum_{pq}C_{pq}J_{m-p}(x)J_{n-q}(x)\ ,
\qquad
x=2/F\ .
$$
Inserting the ansatz in the Schrödinger equation yields an equation for the coefficients $C_{pq}$. I then found the following infinite sum of products of Bessel functions
$$
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}J_{n}(x)J_{n-k_1}(x)J_{n-k_2}(x)J_{n-k_3}(x)
$$
where $k_i$ ($i=1,2,3$) are arbitrary integers. Any chance to get a close expression for the summation? Thanks!

Comment: It would be really helpful to know the context in which such a series arises. It looks like a generalization of the sum formula, given by the Jacobi-Anger expansion $$ e^{iz\cos\theta}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}i^n J_n(z) \cos(n\theta).$$

Comment: I added more details, although the topic is a little technical.

Comment: Since the answer below was marked as accepted, I assume it gave you a closed expression for the sum? If so, I would be happy if you wanted shared it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Neumann's formula:
$$ J_\nu(x)\,J_\mu(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_{\nu+\mu}(2x\cos\psi)\cos((\mu-\nu)\psi)\,d\psi$$
we have that:
$$ J_{n}(x)\,J_{n-k_1}(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_{2n-k_1}(2x\cos\psi)\cos(k_1 \psi)\,d\psi$$
$$ J_{n-k_2}(x)\,J_{n-k_3}(x) = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}J_{2n-k_2-k_3}(2x\cos\psi)\cos((k_3-k_2) \psi)\,d\psi$$
so:
$$J_n(x)\,J_{n-k_1}(x)\,J_{n-k_2}(x)\,J_{n-k_3}(x)\\=\frac{4}{\pi^2}\iint_{(0,\pi/2)^2}J_{2n-k_1}(2x\cos\psi)J_{2n-k_2-k_3}(2x\cos\phi)\cos(k_1\psi)\cos((k_2-k_3)\phi)\,d\psi\,d\phi$$
and we just need to evaluate:
$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_{2n-k_1}(u)\,J_{2n-(k_2+k_3)}(v) $$
through:
$$ e^{i z\cos\theta} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} i^n J_n(z)\, e^{ni\theta}.$$
Then integrate over $\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2$. Continues.